# Set-AzStorageBlobContent is not connecting

Tags: azure, powershell

i am using Set-AzStorageBlobContent in my powershell script but error showing Set-AzureStorageBlobContent is not recognize,   i have installed all az module can someone suggest why it showing like that? code demanding the az modules only.

Comment: Please make sure that you have connected with powershell using `Connect-AzAccount` and az module installed in your enviornment. Reference:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-8.1.0#installation

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose- yes i am able to connect Connect-AzAccount.

Answer (score 0):

***We have tried the to upload a named profile for testing purpose to blob using*** [**`Set-AzStorageBlobContent`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-8.1.0#examples)  ***and it works successfully***. ***Below is  the workaround we followed***.

**`Cmdlts:-`**

```
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "ContosoUpload" -File ".\PlanningData" -Blob "Planning2015"
```

***OUTPUT SCREENSHOT WITH `$PSversionTable` details FOR REFERENCE***:-

[image]
[image]

Version details :-

[image]
[image]

**NOTE:-** ***Once you have installed Az-modules ,Then if the issue still persists please try to restart the PowerShell and try again it should work.***